# What are the best alternatives of Jackrabbit/OAK?

Tags: jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

We are building services for a CMS and we went ahead with Jackrabbit. But as we are moving towards production, we are 
getting into many issues like authentication/authorization, scaling, etc.

Our implementation was with Jackrabbit 2.18 with Mysql DB.

But due to lack of community support we are exploring other options.

Is there any other better solution / alternatives to Jackrabbit or Oak ?

Or Oak with mongodb or cassandra may give better performance ?

Comment: It depends. What exactly are the problems you are running into? But yes, Jackrabbit is in maintenance mode, while Oak gets most of the attention.

Comment: While implementing custom security, I need to enable token based authentication + authorization.
Now I am unable to get usermanagement object from session, due to lack of documentation I am unable to crack it.
Repository repository = RepositoryImpl.create(config);
session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
            JackrabbitSession jackrabbitSession = (JackrabbitSession) session;
            PrincipalManager um = jackrabbitSession.getPrincipalManager();

Comment: I have the same question. It seems JCR-OAK is not very popular search subject on stackoverflow, are there better alternatives that offer full-text-search? Also, the jackrabbit oak documentation recommends using OSGI when using RDB storage, that seems like an End-of-life technology, and I can't find a good explanation for why the Jackrabbit people say to use it.